# Replace Ajax Callback with Jquery callback

Tags: ajax, jquery

How to replace the following ajax callback method with a jquery callback method ?

```
function PostCall() {
  $('#txtRes').val('Please Wait......');
  var reqval = $('#txtReq').val();
  $.ajax({
    url: "myPage",
    type: 'post',
    data: "{'name':'" + reqval + "'}",
    async: true,
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function (result) {
      $('#txtRes').val(result);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: what do you mean? you are currently using jquery's ajax method.

Comment: Is there any other way that I can get the same result without making use of ajax method ?

Comment: Seems like you want to update a part of your webpage without reloading it completely. jQuery's ajax method is just a wrapper for the javascript XMLHTTPRequest(Ajax) implementation. You can use any other library that can handle ajax requests of course. But after all you'll always end up using ajax for the communication between your browser and the server. So you can either way reload your whole page handling whatever you want to do on the server side and only display the new `state` or you go with ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Just append the success at the end of your ajax statement (for example):

```
}.success(function(){
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stick with Ajax go the jQuery 1.8 way and try this:

```
function PostCall() {
    $('#txtRes').val('Please Wait......');
    var reqval = $('#txtReq').val();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'myPage',
        type: 'post',
        data: "{'name':'" + reqval + "'}",
        dataType: 'json',
        async: true,
        contentType: "application/json",
    })
    .done(function(result) {
        $('#txtRes').val(result);
    })
    .fail(function(jqXhr, textStatus) {
        console.log('Error: ...' + textStatus);
    })
    .always(function() {
    });
}
```

The `.done()` function replaces your `success` callback.

If Ajax is not an option for you check out:

- [WebSockets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6753587/best-alternative-to-ajax?answertab=votes#tab-top)
- Http POST Requests (requires the whole page to be reloaded)